# how to make form view with user is foreign key and one model has foreign key relationship with another model?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

my model.py is

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Question(models.Model):
    asker = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='questions')
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from .models import Question,Choice

class PollForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        exclude = ()
postinline=inlineformset_factory(Question, Choice, form=PollForm, extra=1)
```

how should i edit the view tomake the maximum amount of choices to be three
and make the authenticated user is asker of the question 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want something like this

```
def post_create(request):
    form = ModelForm (request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)

    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.asker= user
        instance.save()

   context = {
        "form": form
    }

    return render (request,"blog/create.html",context)
```

Comment: ignore the render part I take out this snippet from one of my projects

Comment: but how i can integrate the inline form

Comment: How do you want to doit,,like I choose in the dropbox a name or what?

Comment: i want it to appear the same way it shows in django admin at least then put a limit to choices that max numbers of choices is three as the way it appear in django tutorial [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_images/admin10t.png)